# Not understanding class vs instance variables in python

Tags: python

I'm having a misunderstanding about python classes/variables when used in an array.  Given the below example, I would expect each 'basket' to have only one 'apple'.  Yet each one ends up with 5?  Why is that and how can I fix my code?

```py
class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        return

class Basket:
    apples: list[Apple] = list()
    def add_apple(self, apple):
        self.apples.append(apple)

baskets = list()
for i in range(5):
    # I'm instantiating a new basket here, why do apples keep getting added to the 'old' baskets that are in the baskets array?
    b = Basket()
    a = Apple()
    b.add_apple(a)
    baskets.append(b)

for b in baskets:
    print(len(b.apples))
```

Comment: `apples` is a class variable - it is shared by all instances of the Basket class. You need to define it inside `__init__` if you want each instance to have its own list. [Relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Comment: See [Object-Oriented Programming in Python](https://realpython.com/oop-in-python-vs-java/#object-attributes).

Comment: Can't find duplicate, but it must exist. Here's article about mutable function arguments:
https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

In short, `apples` is initialized once when class is created (class, not instance). So all `Basket` instances share the same `apples` list (because it's mutable). To fix this behavior, move this initialization code into `__init__` method, it will make `apples` an instance attribute instead.

Comment: To see that difference, you can try `assert baskets[0].apples is baskets[1].apples` - it will not throw, so the list instances are exactly the same and all attributes point to the same object.

Comment: @chepner yeah noticed, i deleted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined `Basket.apples` as a class attribute, meaning it's shared by all `Basket` instances!  Make it an instance attribute by defining it in `__init__` and attaching it to the `self` instance:

```
class Apple:
    pass


class Basket:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.apples: list[Apple] = []

    def add_apple(self, apple: Apple) -> None:
        self.apples.append(apple)
```

Each time you make a new `Basket`, `Basket.__init__` is called on the new instance, and `self.apples = []` is executed, creating a new list that belongs to the new instance.  Now if you execute the rest of the code, you get the output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

because each basket contains one unique `Apple`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable apples is bound to the class not the instance of the class. You can change that via

```py
class Basket:
    def __init__(self):
         self.apples =[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Every instance of `Basket` is sharing the same *class* attribute `apples`. You want an *instance* attribute attached to each instance.

```
class Basket:
    apples: list[Apple]

    def __init__(self):
        self.apples = []

    def add_apple(self, apple):
        self.apples.append(apple)
```

The `apples: list[Apple]` is optional, only needed by a static type checker, not the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

As a list is a mutable element, you chosed to append to `self.apples`. But you probably did not realized that `self.apples` was a reference the a class variable. So for each basket, you added an apple to the same list... And the 5 basket indeed shared that common list.